# Jquery slider affecting other elements on page

Tags: jquery, html, css, squarespace

The question is rather vague and quite difficult to explain without viewing the site I'm having the problem with. Have a look [here](http://www.mayfair-nurses.com/).

Firstly this was done in Squarespace so I don't know if this is a contributing factor. But if you look closely every time the slider transitions, the 2 paragraphs below it jerks a bit.

[image]

I've tried to look at what might cause the paragraphs to jump at slider transition, but honestly I don't know what to even look for. Logically I don't know how this can happen or why. Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your using hardware acceleration to perform the animation this is unfortunately one of the side effects. It's quite difficult to overcome this as its part of a fundamental way in which Chrome renders text.

You can set the `#slidershow-container` to use `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);` or alternatively add `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to elements that exhibit this jitter. The downside to this is that it will change the way the text looks rendered in.

Comment: Thanks for the great insight! I had absolutely no idea. Let me try what you suggested. Then I will decide if it's worth sacrificing the the way the text gets rendered, or just deal with it.

Comment: Okay so I tried both suggestions. The first didn't work. And the second had a minimal effect but the way the text looked rendered just didn't make it worth it for me. So for the visitors using Chrome.. deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

try giving `z-index` to the div containing that gallery.. cz it looks like when the new image appears in gallery that time only those `div` containing text moves...